# Filtering callgrind capture based on shared library name

Tags: valgrind, gprof, callgrind

I would like to have a coarse filter for my callgrind output.

If I ask callgrind to capture a run, I want to tell it to prune at a `.so` level.

For instance, I would like to tell it that it should not collect calls inside `ligGLX.so` shared library.

I have not been able to find out how I can do this. There is an option to toggle collect for a specific function, but I am looking for pruning options.

I also tried dealing with this post-capture, and tell `gprof2dot.py` to prune for a path. But I have not been able to do so successfully. Any path I specify results into an empty `.dot` file.

Comment: Can you do this with scripting based of the callgrind output file format https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-format.html ?